# Enigma in applying Lebesgue dominated convergenege theorem

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $p\in
\mathbb{C}
\lbrack z],~p=p\left(  re^{it}\right)  ,n=\deg p$ and we want to compute de
limit
$$
\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{p^{\prime}\left(
re^{it}\right)  re^{it}}{p\left(  re^{it}\right)  }\operatorname*{dt}%
=\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}F\left(  r\right)  =\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}%
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f\left(  r,t\right)  \operatorname*{dt}.
$$

Since $x\mapsto xp^{\prime}\left(  x\right)  /p\left(  x\right)  $ is
continous on $
\mathbb{C}
$ and
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{p^{\prime}\left(  re^{it}\right)  re^{it}%
}{p\left(  re^{it}\right)  }=n,
$$
hence $x\mapsto xp^{\prime}\left(  x\right)  /p\left(  x\right)  $ is bounded.

Then exists $K>0$ such that
$$
\left\vert \frac{p^{\prime}\left(  re^{it}\right)  re^{it}}{p\left(
re^{it}\right)  }\right\vert <K,\forall\left(  r,t\right)  \in
\mathbb{R}
_{+}\times\lbrack0,2\pi].
$$
So, the conditions of Dominated convergence theorem are verified for
$f_{n}=f_{r},$ then
$$
\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{p^{\prime}\left(
re^{it}\right)  re^{it}}{p\left(  re^{it}\right)  }\operatorname*{dt}=\frac
{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}\frac{p^{\prime}\left(
re^{it}\right)  re^{it}}{p\left(  re^{it}\right)  }\operatorname*{dt}=n.
$$
Just a little problem I have to ask you: here $r\in%
\mathbb{R}
_{+},$ so $f_{r}$ is a kind of generalised sequence and in Lebesgue theorem
$f_{n}$ is defined with $n\in%
\mathbb{N}
$; it is correct to apply this theorem in that case?

Comment: Yes because $\lim_{r\to \infty} f(r) = L \iff\lim_{n\to \infty} f(r_n)=L$ for every sequence $r_n\to \infty.$

Comment: "Since x\mapsto xp^{\prime}\left(  x\right)  /p\left(  x\right) is continous on \mathbb{C}". Sure about that? I'm seeing a pole at $1$ for $p(z) = z - 1$ for instance.

Comment: Yes, I am sure and I am sorry, but I lost some details on the road...here $x=re^{it}$ and I suppose that $p$ has no roots in $\mathbb{C}$ because I used this in the proof by contradiction of d'Alemebert theorem (FTA). Since $F(r)$ is the number of roots in the ball of radius $r$ (this results using winding number of a plane curve) which here we take it $0$ and on the other hand is $n$, so the contradiction.

Comment: Oh, you assume continuity and proceed by contradiction. Fair enough.